# Using octal escape sequence in C

Tags: c

Why

```
printf("%s\n","\061");
```

prints `1` in output. I expect something like `=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

061 octal == 49 decimal == 0x31 hex. That's the ASCII code for the character `'1'`

Why do you expect `'='`?

Comment: The ASCII value of `'='` is `61` (`== 075 == 0x3D`), which is probably related to the confusion.

Comment: Maybe the OP should also have specified the encoding used by his output console.

Answer (score 2):

Edited as per @rici's advice (read comment below..)

Because `\ddd` is character octal representation. `\061` is octal (not decimal) ascii code of '1' and whether you write  `'\61'` **(it's not decimal)** or `'\061'` is one and same thing.

You should refer to ascii table for clarification ..http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Removing the `0` changes nothing. In C, `\ddd` escapes are always octal, with or without the leading 0. http://ideone.com/ukL0e1

Answer (score 1):

`061` is an octal value having decimal value of `49`. `075` in octal is ASCII value for `=`.
Try this to print `=`

```
printf("%s\n","\075");
```